# Comparing two implementations of strcpy()

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I have these two functions that do the same thing (`strcpy()` function):

**First implementation:**

```
void strcpy(char* des_str, const char* src_str) 
{ 
   int j = 0; 
   while ((dest_str[j] = src_str[j])!= '\0')) 
   j++; 
}
```

**Second implementation:**

```
void strcpy(char* des_str, const char* src_str) 
{ 
   while ((*dest_str = *src_str)!= '\0')) 
   { 
      src_str++;
      dest_str++; 
   } 
}
```

Which style/implementation do `C` programmers prefer usually? The *"array"* approach or the *"pointers"* approach? Are there differences other than "aesthetic" differences between the two implementations?

Comment: I prefer: `while (*dest_str++ = *src_str++);`

Comment: in the second you use a extra inc command, witch well reflect if you use the function a lot.

Comment: both have a superfluous  `!= '\0'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd bet the generated machine code will be exactly the same for both. (With optimization)

Therefore, it's only a matter of readability: use the version you and your team are most familiar with. The most important thing here, is that when any programmer sees this source code, he/she does not have to lose time thinking at what this function does.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I'm asking because I thought there might be minor differences in the running time.

Comment: IBM XLC 11 (which is what I have at hand) generates exactly identical assembly for these two functions (and the more usual `while (*dest_str++ = *src_str++);`

Answer (score 1):

As specified by Didier the machine generated code will look same and the performance in this case is also going to be same. But, I would suggest

1) using strncpy rather than using strcpy. 
         strncpy(des, src, noOfcharToCopy);

2) better copy from src end to des end rather than starting from beginning;
   bcz think of case, if src start at address 105 and it is of size 10 and des start at
   address 100 then src data will overwrite on des at 105 address.
   it say "des" should hold real value then src.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the programmer I'd say.
The main difference is in the first implementation you create a new variable and just modify this one, in the second you modify two existing variables. It's a matter of size versus speed (but at a much much small scale)

Answer (score -1):

First implementation i.e. the array implementation is correct and preferred. 
But it depends on the programmer. Best practice is not to change/alter the pointer i.e.  starting/base address should be preserved, should not be incremented or decremented.

Answer (score -2):

as far as I'm aware this one is more common:

```
void strcpy(char* des_str, const char* src_str) 
{ 
  while ((*dest_str = *src_str)!= '\0')) 
  { 
    src_str++;
    dest_str++; 
  } 
}
```

I can only assume because it doesn't require any memory to be allocated (the int)
although more accurately, i assume its usualy implemented as

```
++src_str
++dest_str
```

because the postfix increment has to create a new int to use as the "previous value" before being incrememnted

Comment: This is a C question. There's no performance difference between a standalone preincrement and postincrement. As opposed to in the language that has postincrement in its name and therefore wants everyone to use preincrement.

Comment: true enough, although as Didier Trosset has pointed out, it would be optimised away anyway by pretty much every compiler out there.

Comment: @Art This just stroke me : If one wants to use C++ he must use C first. That makes sense !